# LockBox 3 - PKCS padding does not seem to be supported

Tags: delphi-10-seattle, lockbox-3, pkcs#5

I have a class hierarchy which abstracts the Lockbox crypto components.
Specifically, we are interested in AES-265 with PKCS#5 padding.

The class instance is set correctly with CBC and **the encoding explicitly set to ANSI** but the resulting output is scrambled, which means that the padding is off. 
Alas, CBC supports more than one padding scheme and I think Lockbox isn't using the one we need.

Do you have any ideas where I am going wrong?

This is the class hierarchy's relevant code:

```
TsmEncryptBase = class(TInterfacedObject, IsmEncryption)
private
  FLib: TCryptographicLibrary;
protected
  FCodec: TCodec;
  function Encrypt: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
  function Decrypt: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
public
  constructor Create(const APassword: string;
     const aCipherId: string = 'native.AES-256';
     const aChainModeId:string = 'native.CBC');
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TsmEncryptBase.Create(const APassword: string; const aCipherId:
    string; const aChainModeId: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FLib   := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
//  FLib.RegisterBlockChainingModel( TPure_ECB.Create as IBlockChainingModel);

  FCodec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  FCodec.CryptoLibrary  := FLib;
  FCodec.StreamCipherId := uTPLb_Constants.BlockCipher_ProgId;
  FCodec.BlockCipherId := aCipherId;
  FCodec.ChainModeId := uTPLb_Constants.CBC_ProgId;
  FCodec.Password := APassword;
end;

TsmFileEncryptAES = class(TsmEncryptBase)
private
 FPlainTextFileName: string;
 FEncryptedFileName: string;
protected
  function Encrypt: boolean; override;
  function Decrypt: Boolean; override;
public
  constructor Create(const APlainTextFileName, AEncryptedFileName,
     APassword: string);
end;

constructor TsmFileEncryptAES.Create(const APlainTextFileName, AEncryptedFileName,
    APassword: string);
begin
  inherited Create(APassword);
  FPlainTextFileName := APlainTextFileName;
  FEncryptedFileName := AEncryptedFileName;
  FCodec.Encoding := TEncoding.ANSI;
end;
```

The code is used like so:

```
procedure TForm1.AESFileDecryptClick(Sender: TObject);
var lEncrypt: IsmEncryption;
begin
   lEncrypt := TsmFileEncryptAES.Create(AESFileSaveTo.AsString,
     AESSourceFile.AsString, AESFileKey.AsString);
   lEncrypt.Decrypt;
end;
```

Any ideas?